# How do you handle cookies with webrequest/response as in a proxy?

Tags: c#, cookies, .net-3.5

How do you handle cookies and with webrequest/response as in a proxy?
I'm not sure how to do this...or if I even can.

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify what you mean? What is the setup here?
If you want to perform multiple related operations, then [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx) may be more appropriate; this might (I haven't checked - never needed it) retain cookies between calls on the same WebClient instance (and is a lot easier to use, too).